# Intellij runtime classpath setting

Tags: intellij-idea, classpath, urlclassloader

When i try to run a testNG case, intellij will print these info in console:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\java" -ea -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Didea.launcher.port=7539 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4\bin" **-classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4\lib\util.jar"** -Dfile.encoding=GBK com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapperC:\Users\xufei.xf\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath2884092874744737935.tmp com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -port 65182 -usedefaultlisteners false -socket65183 -temp C:\Users\xufei.xf\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng4985883226383677033.tmp

As you can see, Intellij set the -classpath option, when I debug, I found the code

(URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

can't load the other jars(maven dependence jar..) but only load 
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4\lib\util.jar

So I wonder maybe Intellij change the classpath, so classloader can't load the classes that I need in runtime?

I also try to run the code in eclipse, it's ok.

Comment: Have you added "other jars" as dependences?

Comment: problem is I can run the program in eclipse, but not in intellij. so I have to say, Intellij changes something like classpath, but how?

Comment: So you are using a maven project?

Comment: What kind of 'program' is it? A standalone jar file? web app? enterprise app? Try importing the eclipse .project file into IntelliJ